# Unable to push sinatra app to heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

having trouble pushing my sinatra app to heroku based on the current setup. I have looked through all of the docs on [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack) to figure this out but alas, i'm without resolution and continue to get the following error. `No default language could be detected for this app.`

```
app
    --.git
    -- public
    -- views
    - app.rb
    - config.ru
    - gemfile
    - Gemfile.lock
    - Procfile
    - foo.csv
```

> Procfile

```
web: bundle exec ruby app.rb -p $PORT
```

> config.ru

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

> Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.4.0"

gem 'sinatra'
```

> app.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'csv'

Tilt.register Tilt::ERBTemplate, 'html.erb'

set :public_folder, 'public'

get "/" do
  erb :index
end
```

**Update**

Still not quite sure what the issue was here. I ended up grabbing the following sinatra/heroku shell from github, and replaced it with the assets from my app. Once I ran a `bundle` and pushed to heroku everything ended up working. I'm sure the issue is structurally nuanced and can be pulled from a deeper look at the working setup, for now - i'm just happy it's working.

https://github.com/runemadsen/Sinatra-Heroku-Template

Comment: Maybe related to setting the buildpack?
 See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks.

Comment: @Puhlze yeah, i've removed the buildpack so it should inherit my apps settings.

Comment: did you try without removing the buildpack?

Comment: @maxpleaner yep tried that too

Comment: Your dir list shows you have a `gemfile`. Are you developing on Windows or Mac? Heroku will look for `Gemfile` to detect a Ruby app, and is running on Linux so is likely to be case sensitive.

Comment: @matt that's a very interesting note, however the Gemfile is capitalized in my app. I tried both ways anyway to no avail.